# angular 2 ag-grid Cannot read property 'api' of undefined by getSelectedRow()

Tags: angular6, ag-grid

I work in project that need to build some table template for showing employee information and the coordinator chose one of the employee to do something i face some problems in something called API that comes from AgGridModule but when i tried to select the row so it can display it in the consoles log . 
but i face a problem :

> StoreComponent.html:2 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'api' of undefined
>   at StoreComponent.push../src/app/Component/store/store.component.ts.StoreComponent.getSelectedRows

can someone help me to solve it

here's my code  :-
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yfdcbn?file=src%2Fstyles.css

Comment: Hello.Check my answer - it must help you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem because you dont define gridApi; You must define griApi in `(gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"` event in your grid HTML ; Than you can use onGridReady in ts like this :

```
onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
}
```

And than you can get your selected rows :

```
  getSelectedRows() {
    const selectedRow = this.gridApi.getSelectedRows();
    console.log(selectedRow);
  }
```

If you stuck , you can check example [EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a24afz?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `#agGrid` to your HTML Template, so that it looks like:

```html
<ag-grid-angular  #agGrid
                  style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" 
                  class="ag-theme-balham"
                  [rowData]="rowData "
                  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
                  rowSelection="multiple"
                  >
```

The reason behind that is that the variable `agGrid` in your component is defined as: `@ViewChild('agGrid') agGrid: AgGridNg2;`.

So you need to define a `#agGrid` HTML template reference variable in your HTML. You can find more information about that [in the Angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-).

Answer (score 0):

In angular 6 with ag-grid 20 when you use Gridoptions with rowData & and you are setting the rowData by using setRowData() you may see this issue. One solution to this is dont configure this and set the Rowdata once you receives data from API